# Making sharp tip on tube

Tags: materials, machining

[image]I am trying to make a meat thermometer probe with stainless tube 3/16" OD.  How is a sharp tip made for a hollow tube? One supplier wants to weld on a solid tip. It seems there should be a machining method instead.  The thermometer tips I see seem all of one piece.

Comment: This video shows a spinning process on a larger tube: https://youtube.com/shorts/o9_Xd7eCAXU?feature=share.

Comment: @Transistor Can you spin a tube to have a sealed end though? That's the main reason I don't see this as achievable via spin-forming on a lathe: the closed end on a hollow tube.

Comment: I think that might actually brazed and finish ground. It has the same profile as the the ones I have. Just on mine the braze seam has a distinctly differently colour. It's difficult to tell in the photo due to reflection but yours does appear to be a more even colour. With it in front of you tilt it under the light at different angles and look for any discolouration that follows a line. I think I see some in the photo right where it starts to narrow. I can show you pictures of the ones I have on Monday at work...if I remember.

Comment: @DKNguyen. I haven't a clue really, but here's a [pipe end closing machine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZWewMWdXarQ).

Comment: @Transistor Hmmmm, now that is interesting.

Comment: you could hack one of these ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=oven+thermometer&iax=images&ia=images&iai=https%3A%2F%2Fi5.walmartimages.com%2Fasr%2Ff442e97b-9b30-4388-a36c-3e2abb42c2bf_1.a36b499b6d8b8d477613681240030414.jpeg

Comment: Hypodermic needles are just cut at a shallow angle; of course they are hollow.  Is there a reason your tip needs to be around cone ?

Comment: @jsotola I may resort to that for prototyping, but not a.final solution. Wish I could find out how they all manage it.

Answer (score 0):

Stainless steel is not the greatest heat conductor so you might actually want to weld on be a reason to weld on a tip of a different material (i.e. solid copper but stainless plated). Another alternative is shrink fitting.

But in terms of doing it yourself, honestly, if you're asking then you don't have access to the machines required anyways. I can think of no way to reproduce such a thing one-off in a machine shop even if you were to spin-form it on a lathe (**EDIT: The main reason I did not think it possible was closing the end on a hollow tube via spin-forming but it appears it is possible at least for some profiles. The profiles I saw you Youtube videos was a considerably larger and blunter, flatter hemisphere than the one on the probe though**)

But you mention about speaking with suppliers so maybe you are paying someone else is to make one for you. The odds aren't good here either. If the mass produced tips you saw are indeed single-piece then they are probably made with non-machining methods such as extrusions and forming which don't even fall under the purview of "machining".

These are mass production methods and use specialized, often custom, machines and are basically only ever capable of making one part. The machine and tooling might cost hundreds of thousands or even millions of dollars but then it sits there all day making millions of the same part and the cost is amortized amongst all the parts to make each part dirt cheap. So if you need a million of them, no problem. If you need less, the initial investment into the machine and other tooling is cost prohibitive. The price paid for extremely low cost per unit was an extremely high initial tooling and setup cost.

Just because something was cheap to make per unit, does not mean the methods used were simple or accessible, nor does it mean that it would be equally cheap just to make a handful. In fact, that's typically where the most impressive (and expensive) tooling is dedicated because low cost per unit matters so much that upfront tooling costs are negligible. Since upfront tooling costs are don't matter nearly as much as per unit costs, a lot of fancy, highly specialized, highly dedicated, finely tuned tooling and methods can be used that just too expensive to be feasible in lower quantity projects.

If you only plan to make a one, or two, or even ten, the manufacturer is not going to suggest a mass production method with extreme upfront tooling cost even if it is within their capabilities. Some businesses specialize in producing parts for customers from general purpose equipment such as mills and lathes, while others specialize in producing entire factories and the specialized mass production machines that go in them. Unless your parts are high value, molds, dies, and extrusion machines are off the table unless you get thousands. Even a hundred might be too few.

However, I have some doubts as to whether they are what you think they are. Because I am holding a couple of thermocouple probes in my hand right now and the tip is clearly brazed on. If you provide photos of the ones you saw that are allegedly single-piece, then I can tell you whether the photo is clear enough for you to even tell, and if so I can tell you if they were brazed or not.

In your case I would just recommend a good shrink fit. It's never going to come out and you get more flexibility to make the head more suited to purpose. This should be well within reach of a machine shop and doesn't need crazy custom machines. It just needs careful tolerances. And with appropriate finish grinding and polishing you won't even be able to see the seam line (apart from colour should you choose a different material). The only reason I can tell my thermocouples are brazed is the different colour of the filler metal. The brazing was finish ground and feels seamless.

Comment: can't figure out how to add a photo to this comment.  The thermometer probes I've seen all seem one piece.  They're so cheap there has to be a standard way to make the tips.

Comment: @GeorgesKaufman Don't mistake "cheap per unit" for "cheap setup and tooling costs". Most of the cheapest things you see have ENORMOUS initial setup and tooling costs. A milled metal box might cost \$2k to make but have nearly zero initial tooling costs, while the tin can that costs $0.10 to make first requires a \$50k or \$100k die to be made which is then used to make million of cans.  So if you're only making one the milled box definitely costs much less.

Comment: Even so, why can't I find a manufacturer who claims to be able to do this?  Not the right search words?

Comment: @GeorgesKaufman Because if you only plan to make a one, or two, or even ten, the manufacturer is not going to suggest a mass production method with extreme upfront tooling cost even if it is within their capabilities. Some businesses specialize in producing parts for customers from general purpose equipment such as mills and lathes, while others specialize in producing entire factories and the specialized mass production machines that go in them. Unless your parts are high value, molds, dies, and extrusion machines are off the table unless you get thousands. Even a hundred might be too few.

Comment: @GeorgesKaufman In your case I would just recommend a good shrink fit. It's never going to come out and you get more flexibility to make the head more suited to purpose. This should be well within reach of a machine shop and doesn't need crazy custom machines. It just needs careful tolerances. And with appropriate finish grinding and polishing you won't even be able to see the seam line (apart from colour should you choose a different material). The only reason I can tell my thermocouple probes are brazed is the different colour of the filler metal. It was finish ground and feels seamless.

Comment: @GeorgesKaufman a typical beginner problem is to have a fixed conceptualisation of what they want. One of the symptoms is that they see a multipart piece as one and cant conceptualize that in fact sometimes two things are merged together. Anyway prototypes and on offs frequently need different manufacturing methods. Its not like you will be deep drawing concept testing platforms for example. Another typical problem is that you evaluate too few ideas, experienced people often test and discard quite a nunber of ideas before comitting.

Comment: @GeorgesKaufman You can just edit the photos into your original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with a stainless steel tube and spin form it on a lathe to the right profile you're 95% of the way there.

Some experimentation might be required, but you can likely use heat to melt the tip and seal it. Or perhaps some kind of brazing or solder.

Depending on how precise the sealing method is, you might only need a quick polish to clean it up, or maybe a final machining step.